# The police officer ordered the gunman (to) drop his weapon

Tags: infinitives, subjunctive-mood

> (1) *The police officer ordered that the gunman **drop** his weapon.*
>
> (2) *The police officer ordered the gunman **to drop** his weapon.*

I think these mean virtually the same. Perhaps, the act of ordering in (1) is more directed to the act of dropping itself than to the gunman, and vice versa in (2).

That said, I'd like to know if there are any other discernible subtle nuances of these sentences. For example, which sounds more urgent? Which sounds more formal? And so on and so forth. And of course, any reasoning behind the differentiation would be appreciated.

### EDIT

To avoid confusion, I have inserted "that" in (1). Sorry about that. Please answer my question based on the revised examples.

Comment: Your first sentence is not grammatical. Your second is.

Comment: @Margana, Is "that" not omissible in (1)?

Comment: Sentence (1) would be ok if direct speech as: . . . ordered the gunman, "Drop your weapon."

Comment: @curious-proofreader, Margana: That's not what I intended. I intended (1) to be "The police officer ordered that the gunman drop his weapon" where "that" was just left out. Please let me know if "that" cannot be left out here.

Comment: @JK2 If context makes it clear that the officer is addressing the gunman, you could say "The officer ordered the weapon dropped."

Comment: "That" cannot be left out.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is right at the line of acceptability, and perhaps just over it.  The reason is that English speakers have two structures to choose from, depending on which [ellipsis] they choose to fill.  The first is a {reduced relative clause} that serves as the direct object of "ordered."

```
The police officer ordered [that] {the gunman drop  his weapon}.
        Subject      verb            {subject verb  direct object}
```

The second is a {bare infinitive phrase} that makes "the gunman" the direct object and the infinitive a complement.

```
The police officer ordered   the gunman         [*to*] drop         his weapon.
      Subject       verb   direct object {infinitve-complement object of infinitve}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reduced relative clause". There's no relative clause in (1) that I know of.

Comment: @JK2 Re-read my answer.  That you know of.  But your readers will try to parse the first (borderline) sentence to fill in an ellipsis.  "Order that X do Y" is one idiomatic way to do it -- by supplying a relative pronoun.  "Order X to do Y" is another -- by supplying a particle.  This is a bad thing.

Comment: I have revised (1).

Answer (score 0):

The most frequent verb construction with "to order" is to order someone to do something. The to-infinitive is necessary, you can't use a bare infinitive.

Another possibility is to order that someone do* something (do* = subjunctive). The subjunctive form is frequent in AmE, BrE would opt for"
to order that someone should do sth.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/order_2

Answer (score -1):

I didn't know what you meant in your comment about "that", until I read deadrat's answer.

I now see what you mean, JK2. Your intended meaning is:

> The police officer ordered that the gunman drop his weapon.

However, the use of "ordered that" implies that a general order has been made (*the Chief of Police ordered that no guns were to be carried*).

In your instance, the officer can really only have given a specific order ***to*** the gunman.

The fact that both curious-proofreader and I misread your intention might indicate that you can't drop "that" and have people understand. What makes the options in your question particularly unclear though, is that you strongly imply it is the word "to" which is missing from your first example, since it is the only change you make in the second example. You do not mention the omission of "that" at all.

Comment: I don't think the sin here is semantic.  Is there any doubt that there is a cop, an armed gunman, and an order from the former to the latter to disarm?  The problem is in presenting the reader with an ambiguous parse tree.

Comment: I have revised (1).